# Is there a function to compute the total score during cross-validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was using sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score to compute cross validation scores,

```
cross_val_score(
    SVC(), 
    X, 
    y, 
    scoring=make_scorer(precision_score, zero_division=1), 
    cv=tscv, 
    n_jobs=-1
)
```

where tscv is my customized TimeSeriesSplit.

But the method returns an array of scores, corresponding to each step of cross validation respectively. (e.g., score in time interval 1, ..., score in time interval 5)

My question is, is there a function to compute the total score in the whole time interval, which is the union of time interval1 to time interval 5, instead of giving 5 scores seperately?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not how cross validation works, there is no "total score over whole set" per se. If you wanted to ask "how well do I do over set X" you have to train on something else, but since you are using cross validation this suggests that you only have X.

CV is a process of estimating "how well would I do if the data was randomly sampled from my disrtibution represented by the training data", same way repeated random splitting would. The only difference is that because of "smart" splitting you get slightly reduced variance. And so it returns your split scores, and if you now want to answer the original question you just **take an average** of these scores.